# Wordpress/Godaddy - cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, server

I have followed most of the questions here, tried changing memory_limit, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, max_execution_time, max_input_time, through .htaccess and php.ini file, but I'm still getting the same error.
Upon asking Godaddy support they are simply giving a scripted response. Stating that there is a problem with your plugins, you should deactivate and see.

Currently, GoDaddy support suggested adding the following configuration in php.ini and deactivate the plugins and it will resolve.

```
memory_limit 5000M
upload_max_filesize 3000M
post_max_size 3000M
max_execution_time 3000
max_input_time 3000
```

But, this error is been from the time of a fresh WordPress installation. So, will deactivating all the plugins lead to resolutions?. Any suggestions??

Because of this, I'm getting connection timeouts and unable to take a backup through admin.

Also, I'm on shared hosting. Site - 247btl.com

[image: curl error 28]

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of playing around with php settings, this error was solved with the following PHP settings:

```
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 32M
upload_max_size = 32M
```

I believe the problem was due to max_execution_time settings. Most of the guides suggested to increase it to 1000 along with increasing memory_limit, but that would lead to long load time. Tried it on a hostinger hosted website as well and it seems to work very well.

Comment: I think `upload_max_size` should be `upload_max_filesize` above.

Answer (score 0):

try to update your WordPress to the latest version if not already done.

Then if the problem is still there, contact hosting company and ask the hosting support team check following
1. your server are running latest version of PHP and the cURL library.

2. increase the Server Memory Limits settings.
3. The cURL error can be a dns related issue. Your hosting company might need to switch dns configuration to OpenDNS : https://www.howtogeek.com/164981/how-to-switch-to-opendns-or-google-dns-to-speed-up-web-browsing/
4. Ask your host if there is some limitation with wp-cron, or if loopback is disabled.
5. Ask your host if there a firewall or security modules (e.g. mod_security ) that could block the outgoing cURL requests.

You can also install the Query Monitor plugin and check the status of the HTTP API Calls in the admin page where the error is displayed.

Comment: thank you, will convey it GoDaddy support. Let's see.

Comment: I again came across the same Error on hostinger this time but on a different website. So, this time I migrated it to a local wamp server. It showed up on the local server as well. So, I changed php settings and increased server memory limits, but still the Error persist. Point 1 and 2 is what I tried. Disabling plugins does not resolve the error. Interestingly deactivating the theme and changing it to default 20 20 solves. Any suggestions?.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by the plugin "Contact Form by BestWebSoft".

If you find yourself in the same situation you have to disable the plugin one by one and refresh the page `/wp-admin/site-health.php` to check if the error is still there.

As explained here [Getting "An active PHP session was detected" critical warning in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377032/getting-an-active-php-session-was-detected-critical-warning-in-wordpress) this is due to a plugin badly developed.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that this issue can be caused by the use of the php session_start function. We had an issue where a developer had written the following.

```
add_action('init', function () 
    { 
        if (!session_id()) { session_start(); } 
    });
```

This will kill the loopback and also disrupt REST API communications. This results in the cURL error 28 mentioned above. Sometimes it is not a complicated reason for the failure.

Answer (score -1):

**For Hostinger go to your Hosting Dashboard, then open PHP configuration option from Advanced menu(see screenshot below)-**

[image]

**After that goto PHP Options tab(see screenshot below)-**

[image]

**Then, Scroll down and change the MAX Execution value to 300(see screenshot below). Here 300 = 5 minutes. And after changing the value save these settings and this problem will get solved.**

[image]

Comment: Please share more details. According to the OP's configuration, the maxExecutionTime was already set to 3000. How does setting it to a lower value resolve the given problem?

Comment: Sometimes changes made by you on .htaccess file or in php.ini file gets overridden by hostinger as they have given a separate options window for updating these settings. So, for hostinger you need to set it from the options which I've explained above. MoreOver 3000 which you are setting is the time in milliseconds (3000 ms= 3 seconds). and from Hostinger UI it is taking time in seconds i.e.( 300s = 5 minutes)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. What makes you think that the OP uses Hostinger?