# WAMP/Wordpress - cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I have been stuck with this error for quite some time now. Earlier I got this error on godaddy and asked it over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61287927/wordpress-godaddy-curl-error-28-operation-timed-out-after-10001-milliseconds). Now I'm getting it on hostinger shared hosting. So I migrated the production copy to local wamp server. I got the same error in the local copy as well.

Most of the people are suggesting it's a server error and stating the following rectification:

1. Check if the server is running latest version of PHP and the cURL library. Update Wordpress and plugins.

   ```
    -  The local copy is running PHP 7.4.6 and the curl library packaged with it. Wordpress, plugins are up to date.
   ```
2. Increase server memory limit

   ```
    - I tried many different combinations of settings. The current settings are:
        memory_limit = 256M
        upload_max_size = 64M
        post_max_size = 64M
        upload_max_filesize = 64M
        max_execution_time = 300
        max_input_time = 1000
   ```

   I tried increasing the memory limit and post max size but it does not solve the issue.
3. It could be DNS related issue, switch to OpenDNS

   - I am getting it on localhost.
4. Ask your host if there is some limitation with wp-cron, or if loopback is disabled.
5. Ask your host if there a firewall or security modules (e.g. mod_security ) that could block the outgoing cURL requests.

Please suggest how should I check for 4 and 5 on wamp server. Is there something I'm missing in terms of php settings.

Error Source - http://jrventurefzellc.com/

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This issue tell you that the remote script was still running when your curl cut off the connection. You have to add a timeout option into your curl request! :)

In wordpress for example

```php
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'timeout'     => 45, // <--- this option
    'headers'     => array(),
    'body'        => array(
        'username' => 'bob',
        'password' => '1234xyz'
    )
);
```

Or PHP curl

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the timeout to my wp_remote_request() not only solved the cURL error, it made my request run much faster.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of playing around with php settings, this error was solved with the following PHP settings:

```
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 32M
upload_max_size = 32M
```

I believe the problem was due to max_execution_time settings. Most of the guides suggested to increase it to 1000 along with increasing memory_limit, but that would lead to long load time. Tried it on a GoDaddy hosted website as well and it seems to work very well.

Update:

After a couple of days, this error had again shown up on the site. Later, through an inspection of function.php, I found that the issue was due to Wp-vcd malware. Removing the respective malware code and files solved it.
[image: WP-VCD affecting curl]

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the timeout parameter. I was facing same issue and it's solved it like a magic:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( $url,
    array(
        'timeout'     => 60, // <-- this one increase to 120 or more
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue with the wp-rocket plugin. But it eventually disappeared after I disabled the Cloudflare CDN and re-enabled it.