# Getting "An active PHP session was detected" critical warning in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests.

Comment: I'm getting "A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests."

Answer (score 31):

In most cases, the real reason of the above errors is the incorrect mechanism for using PHP sessions within plugins or themes when they are using the **session_start()** function.

Now you need to identify what plugin cause this issue by deactive your plugin one by one.

Then in that plugin, you need to find a piece of code similar to this:

```
if ( !session_id() ) {
    session_start();
}
```

then change it to:

```
if ( !session_id() ) {
    session_start( [
        'read_and_close' => true,
    ] );
}
```

Then you are done. In most cases, this will fix the issue. Good luck!

Comment: Might be stating the obvious, but it you need a quick way to list all the occurrences of 'session_start()' in your WP site, from the root of the site:
 grep -r 'session_start()'.
This can help you track down the offending plugin.

Comment: Also be aware that adding 'read_and_close' will break any data stored by the plugin to $_SESSION after session_start(). This will often be the entire reason for calling session_start() in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue due to WP Hotel Booking plugin use. I fixed it! Took me a while to find a plugin it caused and editing the plugin .php didn’t help. But I fixed it adding a snippet of code to functions.php of the CHILD theme:

```
function mymodule_curl_before_request($curlhandle){
session_write_close();
}
add_action( 'requests-curl.before_request','mymodule_curl_before_request', 9999 );
```

There's a background to this solution at: [Make WordPress Core, Loopback request fails if headers set in curl](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/50491)
(Original link in German doesn't exist anymore and was referring to this other related discussion.)

Comment: The weird thing, it doesn't fix the "An active PHP session was detected" warning, but it does fix "The REST API encountered an error" warning...

Comment: @BenKalsky: that's likely because the session is active when the Site Health Check checks for it, but it gets closed by the snippet at the start of the REST API check.

Comment: It worked for me, Could you please let us know how did you find this action? requests-curl.before_request , I searched in the wp codes, we didn't have something like this but it worked properly, could you please explain?

Comment: You had curly apostrophes (’) instead of straight ones (') in your code snippet so it couldn't be copied & pasted directly into wordpress. I've fixed it. However, this snippet still doesn't fix the error, as the first commenter observed. It's not that the session is only closed after the "Active PHP session" error is given, because subsequent runs of health check still show it. It never closes.

Answer (score 3):

Often this critical issue is caused by conflict in SESSION when using the PHP `session_start()` function.
For example I have used a Calculation plugin in Wordpress and after Wordpress version update this error occured.
So I detected the plugin which causes this issue as activated/deactivated plugins one by one.

SOLVING these errors: In File manager of my site I got the .php files of the plugin and searched for `session_start()` function. Where it was used after it I used this function in a row `session_write_close();`

[Source of the function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Regards!

Comment: This saved me some time.
1) Deactive plugins one by one
2) Check health report after each deactived plugin.
3) Once plugin has been identified, you can search the .php files for the session_start(); and add the session_write_close(); to the function.

Answer (score 1):

To chime in with my own experience here, this very issue was resolved by turning off the “cross sell pop up” module of Shopengine Pro. Indeed there’s a session start in the php. I have notified them about this today. Maybe it’ll help someone else meantime!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you get these critical health warnings when you install a plugin or a plugin Adon and fail to complete its setup to the end. So the simplest solution is to deactivate the plugin or complete the plugin set-up. My errors were caused by a Woocommerce Adon which I deactivated and when I refreshed the health status the two issues were gone. I hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For those who narrowed it down to the Unyson plugin causing the error:

Open file manager and navigate to the theme the site is using. In the theme folder there is a 'functions.php' file. Add the following code to the file:

`if (!function_exists('_disable_fw_use_sessions')) { add_filter('fw_use_sessions','_disable_fw_use_sessions'); function _disable_fw_use_sessions(){  return false; } }`

Should look something like this when done.

[Code added to functions.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMLsd.png)

Answer (score 0):

@David M., If the issue is specifically happening with the Cross-Sell Popup Module of the ShopEngine PRO plugin, then it can be fixed by adding a small piece of code on the **cross-sell-popup.php** file that will read and close the session of the Cross Sale Popup module immediately.

Big Thanks to @thống nguyễn for the solution.

On the line 18th, from where the session starts, replace the session_start() with the following code:

```
session_start([
    'read_and_close' => true
]);
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried the above and it's not working try to change the php version from your hosting's CPanel
I had the same error ande i changed the php version from 7.4 to 7.3 and it all went well

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is outdated advice and doesn't really fix anything. Perfect example of "kicking the can down the road".