# I get a "cURL error 28" when I try to install a new plugin or theme

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, ubuntu-20.04

I'm new to WordPress.  I'm trying to complete [the FreeCodeCamp tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O79pJ7qXwoE) now.

The tutorial explains how to install a new them.  Whenever I click **Install** to install a new theme or plugin, the progress circle spins for about 10 seconds, and then I get the following error:

> Installation failed: Download failed. cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Some details about my setup/troubleshooting steps I've taken:

- I have WordPress.org installed on a VM.
- The OS on the VM is Ubuntu Server 20.04.
- The value of $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP is LXQt.
- WordPress Updates says I have the latest version of WordPress (5.9.3).
- Site Health in wp-admin says, "Your site is unable to reach WordPress.org at 198.143.164.251, and returned the error: cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds"

  - Don't know why I'm getting this error.  [A random webpage](https://sternerstuff.dev/2018/04/wordpress-curl-error-28-dns-resolver/) suggests running `curl -s -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null 198.143.164.251`.  I did and 0.088994 was returned (suggesting the issue isn't with curl).
  - I've also already [installed resolvconf](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2018/10/dns-on-ubuntu/) and reconfigured DNS to point to Google's Public DNS.
- Site Health in wp-admin also says I'm running PHP v7.4.3, cURL v7.68.0, and OpenSSL v1.1.1f.  I think these are the latest versions of these software that can be installed on Ubuntu Server 20.04.
- My ufw rules are (these apply for both v4 and v6:

  - 22/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
  - 22 ALLOW Anywhere
  - Apache ALLOW Anywhere
  - 80/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
  - 443/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
- I've ran `sudo ufw disable`, just to see if ufw was causing the issue.  It wasn't; the same issue persisted even after disabling ufw.
- In /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini, `memory_limit = -1`
- I don't have SELinux installed (I ran `sestatus` and Linux told me it couldn't find the command).
- I've already disabled and uninstalled all of the plugins that came with the basic WordPress install.
- I don't have a **modsecurity** directory in `/etc` .
- I can't install the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin.  I'm in catch 22 -- this plugin could help me debug my problem, but I can't install any plugins because of this error I'm getting.
- I've followed [a StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61287927/wordpress-godaddy-curl-error-28-operation-timed-out-after-10001-milliseconds) to reconfigure my PHP file.  Also ran `sudo systemctl restart apache2` for good measure.
- I've added `198.143.164.251 api.wordpress.org` to `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: `Your site is unable to reach WordPress.org at 198.143.164.251` is a network related issue. Your code probably needs to use a proxy for outbound connection, and this address is not whitelisted => your script can't connect to this site.

Comment: I had same issue and it was taking some much time to laod. there is curl and libcurl version different installed on my machine, I have removed it from and installed once again.  It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Oh man, I found the issue.  It's weird how constant googling and trying random things and just taking a break can help.

I was following Ubuntu's tutorial for installing WordPress.  Currently [their webpage says](https://www.tecmint.com/speed-firefox-linux/) to install these packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2 \
                 ghostscript \
                 libapache2-mod-php \
                 mysql-server \
                 php \
                 php-bcmath \
                 php-curl \
                 php-imagick \
                 php-intl \
                 php-json \
                 php-mbstring \
                 php-mysql \
                 php-xml \
                 php-zip
```

Turns out this webpage is missing some other php packages that we need to install.  I found [a DigitalOcean webpage](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-a-lamp-stack) that suggests installing these packages too:  `sudo apt install php-gd php-xmlrpc php-soap`.  I did this, then ran `sudo systemctl restart apache2` again, just to be safe.  After that, I logged in to wp-admin and clicked **Install** for a theme.  The installation was almost instantaneous, no errors.

*(A side note -- I'm using Firefox in the VM, and sometimes the browser was just slow.  Had to follow the directions on [a TechMint page](https://www.tecmint.com/speed-firefox-linux/) to speed things up a bit).*

My bad for not including a link to that Ubuntu page originally.  If I had, I'm assuming someone would've noticed those missing php packages.